# Expression expected.ts(1109) error in React file with constructor and state

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm learning React and trying to understand constructor and state.

I'm getting this weird error as per attachment, please clarify what may be going wrong

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      name: "test",
      age: 30
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.name} </h1>
        <h3>{this.state.age} years old </h3>
      </div>

    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please include code as plain text in a code block for readability and searchability? My guess is the error will become apparent when we can see what's behind that popover.

Comment: @DrewReese updated question, please recheck

Comment: Probably not the cause, but try passing the props that are passed to the constructor to the super. And also add missing semi-colons.

Comment: Strange, after deleting everything in this file and reloading VSCode and re-pasting code the problem disappeared.  VSCode is not as good as IntelliJ or Eclipse, coming from Java world; I find it very buggy and not friendly many a places

Comment: I searched to TS error 1129 but didn't turn up much. I did copy/paste your snippet into a codesandbox and nothing was flagged. Yeah, vscode is great, IMO (having also used intellij/eclipse), but yeah linting can get a little goofy sometimes.

Comment: @vikramvi never come across an issue like this on vscode. and while I liked eclipse, my preference with vs code always, cus it's not limited to java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the issue by closing the file and re-opening it again.
VSCode is putting file in some weird state and showing unrelated errors.
Or just close VSCode and re-open to fix these kind of weird problems